# bone broth..chicken carcass, lamb bones with some meat left out for 3 hours from pressure cooking

Tags: broth

I left my bone broth out after pressure cooking for 3 hours. It was warm when I got home and consisted of a chicken carcass, lamb bones with a bit of meat and the second boiling of marrow beef bones with some vinegar. It gelled so perfectly in the fridge but should we eat it? Would boiling it again for a while make it safe?

Comment: As the first duplicate says, 3 hours is a bit long to be totally safe (though not all that much too long), and as the second says, further cooking doesn't make unsafe food safe again.